# OnGetPlaybackPositionListener not being called

Tags: android, android-widget, android-mediaplayer, lockscreen

I'm developing an android app where I want to enable lockscreen media controls when the user is playing music. For some reason, the OnGetPlaybackPositionListener() callback is not being called when the lockscreen widget is shown, instead the lockscreen widget always assumes progress is 0 (then guesses the progresses from that point until the next pause/play). So basically every time you pause it starts the progress over b/c it is always getting 0.

I placed a log in my code and it never gets logged, making me think something is happening (or I'm not doing something) so that my callback is not registered properly. Pseudo-code is below, anyone has any idea please let me know...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            mRemoteControlClient.setOnGetPlaybackPositionListener(new RemoteControlClient.OnGetPlaybackPositionListener() {
                @Override
                public long onGetPlaybackPosition() {
                    UpLog.d(TAG, "Position = " + mContinuousPlaybackPosition);
                    if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                        return -1;
                    }

                    if (!isErrorState() && getMediaPlayerState() != PlaybackState.UNKNOWN) {
                        return mLastKnownPosition;
                    }

                    return -1;
                }
            });
```

Comment: any updates? I've run into the same problem